# `abs` inside coordinate calculation

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

How can I put `abs` inside a coordinate calculation in TikZ? I have tried the following but it doesn't work (see lines 4 and 5 inside the MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\asd}[1]{\node[circle,draw] at ($(1+#1,0)$) {B};} %this works
\newcommand{\zxc}[1]{\node[circle,draw] at ($abs(#1),0$) {B};} %this doesn't
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] at (1,0) {A};
\zxc{-2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `($({abs(#1)},0)$)` seems to work, `($abs(#1),0$)` would never work anyway, as you are missing the inner `()`'s

Comment: @daleif Sorry - I had removed the inner `()` in my attempts to find a solution before posting here. I confirm that throwing in the extra pair of braces works (but I have no idea why...); if you post this suggestion as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `($({abs(#1)},0)$)`, firstly we of course need `()` inside the coordinate calculation. Secondly in `{abs(#1)}`, the `{}`'s are needed to ensure that the expression is passed on to evaluation and thus does not croak the parser that might be looking for `()`'s and `|-` etc

Comment: Only the curly braces are needed, `({(abs(#1)},0)`, to keep the parentheses balanced, when TeX reads the coordinate.